# Error in getting specific row from python pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I want to extract a row by name from the foll. dataframe:

```
        Unnamed: 1       1       1.1        2      TOT
0                                                     
1         DEPTH(m)    0.01      1.24     1.52      NaN
2   BD 33kpa(t/m3)    1.60      1.60     1.60      NaN
3          SAND(%)   42.10     42.10    65.10      NaN
4          SILT(%)   37.90     37.90    16.90      NaN
5          CLAY(%)   20.00     20.00    18.00      NaN
6          ROCK(%)   12.00     12.00    12.00      NaN
7       WLS(kg/ha)    2.60      8.20     0.10     10.9
8       WLM(kg/ha)    5.00      8.30     0.00     13.4
9      WLSL(kg/ha)    0.00      3.80     0.10      3.9
10     WLSC(kg/ha)    1.10      3.50     0.00      4.6
11     WLMC(kg/ha)    2.10      3.50     0.00      5.6
12    WLSLC(kg/ha)    0.00      1.60     0.00      1.6
13   WLSLNC(kg/ha)    1.10      1.80     0.00      2.9
14     WBMC(kg/ha)    3.40    835.10   195.20   1033.7
15     WHSC(kg/ha)   66.00   8462.00  1924.00  10451.0
16     WHPC(kg/ha)  146.00  18020.00  4102.00  22269.0
17      WOC(kg/ha)  219.00  27324.00  6221.00     34.0
18     WLSN(kg/ha)    0.00      0.00     0.00      0.0
19     WLMN(kg/ha)    0.00      0.10     0.00      0.1
20     WBMN(kg/ha)    0.50     92.60    19.30    112.5
21     WHSN(kg/ha)    7.00    843.00   191.00   1041.0
22     WHPN(kg/ha)   15.00   1802.00   410.00   2227.0
23      WON(kg/ha)   22.00   2738.00   621.00   3381.0
```

I want to extract the row containing info on WOC(kg/ha). here is what I am doing:

```
df.loc['WOC(kg/ha)']
```

but  I get the error:

```
*** KeyError: 'the label [WOC(kg/ha)] is not in the [index]'
```

Comment: How did you import this, if you used `read_csv` then you could set the `index_col` to your first index `pd.read_csv(file, index_col=[0])`

Comment: Not getting it through a csv. It is coming in as a list which gets converted to dataframe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have that label in your index, it's in your first column the following should work:

```
df.loc[df['Unnamed: 1'] == 'WOC(kg/ha)']
```

otherwise set the index to that column and your code would work fine:

```
df.set_index('Unnamed: 1', inplace=True)
```

Also, this can be used to set index without explicitly specifying column name: `df.set_index(df.columns[0], inplace=True)`

Comment: thanks @EdChum, can I get the first column by position somehow?

Comment: You can set the index so `df.set_index('Unnamed: 1', inplace=True)` and then your code would work

Comment: Also, this can be used to set index without explicitly specifying column name: `df.set_index(df.columns[0], inplace=True)`